# How do I keep a value generated in a TableViewCell even I select other cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a `Button` in a `TableViewCell`. If a user touches the Button, it counts how many times it's touched and I am using it as an `index`. A problem is **I'd like to save how many times each cells are touched**, but now if I touch another Cell, it just becomes initial value as the photo. Anyone could give me any advice? Here's my sample code.

I tried, making another global variable and save there, or make it a func and return the value but everything didn't work.

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var index = [0, 0, 0]


    @IBAction func buttonInCell(_ sender: Any) {

        // if I touch First Cell index[0] += 1
        if indexPath!.row == 0 {              

            if index[0] < timeArr.count {

                print("First Cell: \(index[0])")
                index[0] += 1

            }
        }
        // If I touch Second Cell index[1] += 1
        else if indexPath!.row == 1 {

            if index[1] < timeArr.count {

                // I want this value be same as the last value I got from First Cell
                // If I touched First Cell 3 times the output should be '2' but it shows '0' now
                print("Second Cell: \(index[0])") 
                // print(index[1]) 
                index[1] += 1

            }
        }

    }  
}
```

[image]

Comment: sir each cell is initiated with value [0,0,0] .. so when you tap second cell .. it have [0,0,0], data is not shared between cells

Comment: @jawadAli Yes, index[0] is what I want to check. I want to keep the '2' value of index[0], but if I touch the second cell index[0] value becomes 0 which is initial value

Comment: what you want to do ?

Comment: @jawadAli Hmmm I am still figuring out. Anyway your advice was great though

Comment: Thank you .. i just wanted to know what you want to achieve... so that i become able to guide you